# GoDaddy CakePHP subfolder .htaccess rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I need to setup cakephp in the sub directory of my site - `cms`. I tried various `.htaccess` rules but I get error `500` and `404` error. I am on GoDaddy Deluxe Linux Hosting with cPanel.

Following is what I tried.

In CMS folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cms/
#RewriteBase /mysite.com/cms/
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In CMS > App folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cms/
#RewriteBase /mysite.com/cms/
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

In CMS > App > Webroot:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cms/
#RewriteBase /mysite.com/cms/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Kindly help me get the working .htaccess rules.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use proper `RewriteBase`.

Try:

**In CMS > App folder:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cms/app/

RewriteRule    ^$   webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**In CMS > App > Webroot:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cms/app/webroot/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Your `/cms/.htaccess` looks fine.

Comment: What is the name of the folder your cakephp app lives?

Comment: That comment is of no use. What didn't work, what error you got? What URL you entered in browser?